# execute action when .js file loads

Tags: struts2

Question: 
is there any way to execute an action on a welcome.jsp file?

My problem:
My welcome.js file has string literals substituted by java properties like:

```
<button value"${com.button.ok.literal}" ...
```

And they get substituted when an action is executed, the problem is the initial doesn't execute any action and thus there's no substition, the struts.xml looks like:

```
<action name = "createProcess" class = "com.acme.actions.Init" method="create">
            <result name ="ok">/jsp/welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I tried to execute an empty action 'loadLabels', by defining in welcom.js init():

```
funcion init(){
...
        <%
                String checkfirst = (String)request.getAttribute("checkfirst");
        %>
            if ("<%=checkfirst %>" != "first"){
                document.forms[0].action ="loadLabels.action?parameter=first";
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
```

This works, but i'm 100% sure there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Just redirect from welcome jsp to action.

Comment: Use Jquery ajax to load that function

Answer (score 0):

You can always embed a javascript function in your page and call to it whenever need be to execute your action. The javascript code would be a little something like

```
window.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/actionName";
```

Call to it something like

```
<input type="button" value="Welcome!" onclick="welcomeActionFunction">
```

Comment: And how would the struts.xml would look like if i want to execute the action just once in init() method?